# Vue i10n in component

Tags: vue.js, locale

I use the plugin [vue i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n). Code example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ test }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        layout: "default",
        label: this.$t('Tools'),

        data: () => ({
            test: this.$t('Test')
        })
    }
</script>
```

But it does not work. The plugin has not yet been initialized, so it cannot translate strings. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: So you admit that the plugin has not been initialized? Then why not in your main JS file add in the initialing script needed? I don't know the plugin you're using, so I can't be more specific

Comment: This plugin: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

Comment: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html#compatibility-note

Comment: I  did not find a solution to my problem in the manual. I can translate only in the context of the calculated properties, but not in the context of the data block.

Comment: I don't know as I've never used it, but you may want to look into `<p v-html="$t('message.hello')"></p>`

Comment: Yes, it is easy. The problem is in translating the properties that are in the block Data. Or outside the date block, calculated propertie e t c. For example, variable Label, in my code.